# Querying MongoDB in Flask app with PyMongo is suddenly very slow?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, heroku, pymongo

I've created a Flask app and deployed it successfully to Heroku. I'm using MongoDB as my database connected via PyMongo. The application is almost entirely done and has been successfully deployed to Heroku with everything (including DB connection and response times) working as expected until now.

For some reason as of yesterday, seemingly out of the blue, queries to MongoDB are taking **significantly** longer than in the past. So much so that my Herkou app is now timing out with an H12 error:

```
2022-01-25T15:37:08.480043+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.studynorthernpomo.com request_id=36797415-4424-4a42-bd7e-d333cae18acb fwd="64.201.141.142,172.69.68.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=2841 protocol=http
2022-01-25T15:37:08.480223+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.41.18 - - [25/Jan/2022:15:37:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2686 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
2022-01-25T15:37:40.502643+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/sentences" host=www.studynorthernpomo.com request_id=6fb82f89-dd43-409e-9054-7aa8fa745a4b fwd="64.201.141.142,172.69.68.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2022-01-25T15:37:40.670740+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 15:37:40 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:18)
2022-01-25T15:37:40.671406+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 15:37:40 +0000] [18] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18)
```

I am certain that this is an issue with the database connection as opposed to the app itself because I am having the same issue locally and on the deployed version. Locally the connection goes through, but only well after two minutes. Previously locally connecting to the database took longer than the deployed version, but only by a few extra seconds.

Here is the "/sentences" route which is causing the slowness:

```
@app.route('/<category>')
    def sets(category):
        outset = ''
        bins = []
        bin_counts = []
        all_vocab = []
        all_counts = 0

        if category == 'phrases':
            outset = category
            all_vocab = list(mongo.db.phrases.find({}))
            all_counts = len(all_vocab)
            bin_counts = [len(list(mongo.db.phrases.find({'sets': bin}))) for bin in bins]
            session['current_set'] = 'phrases'
        elif category == 'sentences':
            outset = category
            bins = ["I am Kim.", "Who are you?", "Where are you from?",\
            "I am from ___.", "We are here.", "How are you?", "I’m good. I’m bad. I’m tired.",\
            "I’m not good. I’m not bad. I’m not tired.", "Your friend is tired.",\
            "Is that your car?", "Is this your car?", "Are you tired? No, I’m not tired.",\
            "Are you Kelly? No, I’m Kim.", "Are you from ___? No… yes…",\
            "Is she your relative? No… yes…", "Call me! (Commands)"]
            bin_counts = [len(list(mongo.db.sentences.find({'sets': [bin]}))) for bin in bins]
            all_vocab = list(mongo.db.sentences.find({}))
            all_counts = len(all_vocab)
            session['current_set'] = 'sentences'
        else:
            outset = 'words'

        return render_template('sets.html', outset=outset, bins=enumerate(bins), bin_counts=bin_counts, all_counts=all_counts, all_vocab=all_vocab)
```

When I add some extra print statements to see what is taking so long, it appears that this line is causing the timeout: `bin_counts = [len(list(mongo.db.sentences.find({'sets': [bin]}))) for bin in bins]`. However this is very confusing to me as I did not change this line of code and the app was working with relatively good speeds prior to yesterday.

**[BEGIN EDIT]**

And here is how I am connecting to the DB. Of course, I've replaced my username, password, and secret key here for privacy. My Flask app is in an application factory:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        MONGO_URI='mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@studynorthernpomo.onskp.mongodb.net/vocabulary?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        SECRET_KEY='---------'
    )
    mongo = PyMongo(app)
```

**[END EDIT]**

Finally, here's what my data looks like in MongoDB:
[database document example from MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfs1F.png). There are 191 documents in the DB I'm querying, each with the following format:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(""),
  english: "english text",
  northern_pomo: "northern pomo text",
  sets: ["list of sets names"],
  audio: Binary("hexadecimal bin", 0)
}
```

Audio files that were uploaded range from 2-10s in length. Some are MP3, some are WAV.

If you have any idea what could be happening or what I could try to try and troubleshoot further your advice is greatly appreciated! I've already scoured the internet for someone else with this issue to no avail.

Please let me know if there's any additional information I can provide to clear up my issue.

Comment: When using frameworks it is difficult to determine what is actually happening.  Since you have so few documents in your database I presume the database is very quick.  You could prove this out by profiling the database interactions and viewing the execution stats for duration of query run.  Assuming the database itself is fast, the other culprits could be network related.  I would start by removing all code that has no effect and limit to only lines of code that present the issue. One thing I don't see in your example code is how you connect to the database.  This is an important aspect.

Comment: Also, on the host running this code verify you are not CPU bound when experiencing the performance issue.

Comment: Also, since you are storing binary data in the database please identify the average size of the BSON documents, the max size, and the min size.

Comment: It doesn't look like the binary data field 'audio' is used in the example code.  You might try to PROJECT it out in this example code to see if serialization is causing slowness.  https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for the suggestions. I've edited my question to include how I connect to the DB. It'll take me a minute, but I'll look into whether or not I'm CPU bound as well as the avg BSON size. Will report back...

Comment: @barrypicker I've done some more investigating and your idea about projecting out the audio has put me on the right path. It seems that when I convert the `pymongo.cursor.Cursor` object to a list with `list()`, the audio binary is causing a severe slowdown. Now I just have to figure out how to work around this... Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome and good luck!